# Connect via VPN to third party from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-direct-connect

We have a number of 3rd party systems which are not part of our AWS account and not under our control, each of these systems have an internal iis server set up with dns which is only available from the local computer. This iis server holds an API which we want to be able to utilise from our EC2 instances.

My idea is to set up some type of vpn connection between the ec2 instance and the 3rd party system so that the ec2 instance can use the same internal dns to call the api.

AWS provide direct connect, is the correct path go down in order to do this? If it is, can anyone provide any help on how to move forward, if its not, what is the correct route for this?

---

Basically we have a third party system, on this third party system is an IIS server running some software which contains an API. So from the local machine I can run `http://<domain>/api/get` and it returns a JSON lot of code. However in order to get on to the third party system, we are attached via a VPN on an individual laptop. We need our EC2 instance in AWS to be able to access this API, so need to connect to the third party via the same VPN connection. So I think I need within AWS a separate VPC.

Comment: AWS Direct Connect is a misnomer. It is not the solution for your case. It is for dedicated network connection to AWS. The problem is not clear to me to suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi hellov, thanks for ur reply. So i'll try and explain it a little better...

We have a third party system, on this third party system is an IIS server running some software which contains an API. So from the local machine I can run http://<domain>/api/get and it returns a json lot of code.

However in order to get on to the third party system, we are attached via a VPN on an individual laptop. We need our EC2 instance in AWS to be able to access this API, so need to connect to the third party via the same VPN connection. Does this make sense?

Comment: It sounds like you already have a VPN server you need to connect to. Just install the appropriate VPN client software on the Linux or Windows EC2 instance and setup the connection.

Comment: AWS direct connect is physical infrastructure that would likely cost 10's of thousands or hundreds of thousands of dollars and many months to set up. All you need is a VPN client/server.

Comment: So there is nothing special I need within Aws like seperate vpc etc. Just a simple openvpn client installed on my EC2 instance connected to remote machine... That's it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer depends on your budget, bandwidth and security requirements.

Direct Connect is excellent. This services provides a dedicated physical network connection from your point of presence to Amazon. Once Direct Connect is configured and running your will then configure a VPN (IPSEC) over this connection. Negative: long lead times to install the fibre and relatively expensive. Positives, high security and predicable network performance.

Probably for your situation, you will want to consider setting up a VPN over the public Internet. Depending on your requirements I would recommend installing Windows Server on both ends linked via a VPN. This will provide you with an easy to maintain system provided you have Windows networking skills available.

Another good option is OpenSwan installed on two Linux system. OpenSwan provides the VPN and routing between networks.

Setup times for Windows or Linux (OpenSwan) is easy. You could configure everything in a day or two.

Both Windows and OpenSwan support a hub architecture. One system in your VPC and one system in each of your data centers.

Depending on the routers installed in each data center, you may be able to use AWS Virtual Private Gateways. The routers are setup in each data center with connection information and then you connect the virtual private gateways to the routers. This is actually a very good setup if you have the correct hardware installed in your data centers (e.g. a router that Amazon supports, which is quite a few).

Note: You probably cannot use a VPN client as the client will not route two networks together, just a single system to a network.

You will probably need to setup a DNS Forwarder in your VPC to communicate back to your private DNS servers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [sshuttle](http://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-it-works.html) can do, what you need. Technically you can open ssh tunnel between your EC2 and remote ssh host. It can also deal with resolving dns requests at remote side. That is not perfect solution, since typical VPN has fail over, but you can use it as starting point. Later, maybe as foll back, or for testing purposes.